# Flask WTForm with SelectField does not work with if form.validate_on_submit

Tags: python, forms, validation, flask

I have created a WTForm with SelectField, but the form is not valid. When I press submit button I do not get any error.

View

```
def add_virtual_assistant():

    form = AddVirtualAssistant()

    url = "http://api.dataatwork.org/v1/jobs"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    form.job.choices = [(i["title"]) for i in data if "title" in i]

    if request.method == "POST":
         if form.validate_on_submit():
            return "ok"
```

My form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class AddVirtualAssistant(FlaskForm):

    job = SelectField("job", choices=[], validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Solution for anyone who read this I solved it with adding print error in the console

```
print(form.errors.items())
```

The error was  ['too many values to unpack (expected 2)'])]) I had list of strings and this was mistake. I changed form choices to

```
list(enumerate([i["title"] for i in data if "title" in i], 1))
```

and the form is valid now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that somehow the returned form is not valid. I suggest to either print out the the error in the form to the logger (it has a simple `form.errors` attribute, or just simply debug with pdb after the post.

With `Selectfield` I think the most possible root of the problem is somehow it can't find the selected option between the choices

Comment: Do you know where I can read how to print out error in the logger? I am trying to read more aboute form.errors, but can not find anything. I am pretty new and I do not know how to use debug

Comment: I have found that I have to add print(form.errors.items())